# Submit form using tampermonkey by clicking a submit type button

Tags: tampermonkey

Im trying to create a script that clicks a button.
the button I need to click on:

`<input type="submit" name="press" value="submit" />`

I can't find a way to press that type of button.

Comment: If this button is part of a form, you will be able to use `document.getElementById('form_id').submit();`

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should include these two lines, so that you can use jQuery:

```
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js
// @run-at  document-end
```

And then all of this will work:

```
$( "input[tpye='submit']" ).click();
$( "input[name='press']" ).click();
$( "input[value='submit']" ).click();
```

or alternatively:

```
$('#form_id').submit();
```